# Calling the 'hex' builtin from the python C API

Tags: python, c

I am building a C extension module for Python 3.x. I would like to access the functionality of the `hex` builtin in the Python layer. That is, I would like to convert (form my C code) a `PyObject*` which is of type '`PyLong_Type`' (that is, a plain python `int`) into a `PyObject*` which is of type `PyUnicode_Type` and represents the hexadecimal coding of the `int` I started with.

This seems like it should be easy, but none of the [functions in the integer section of the API guide](http://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/long.html) seem to do it; neither do any of the [functions in the string section](http://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/unicode.html#unicode-objects). Note in particular that `PyUnicode_FromFormat` doesn't do what I need:

- you can't use it with the `%S` or `%R` format specifier (you'll get a decimal representation)
- you can't use it with the `%x` format specifier (you'd have to convert the `PyObject*` to a C `int` first, which isn't a safe thing to do, since the Python integer might be too large to fit.

Comment: why not just actually call `hex`?

Comment: @MarkReed As in, pull `hex` from the built-ins dict then `PyObject_Call` it? I see that that would certainly work. (It seems like roughly the same amount of work as calling `format` as I propose below.) But I couldn't help wondering whether there was an easier/more canonical way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the implementation of [`hex`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/458181a8b48a/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1274):

```
static PyObject *
builtin_hex(PyObject *self, PyObject *v)
{
    return PyNumber_ToBase(v, 16);
}
```

It's `static`, but the implementation suggests an easy way to get the same functionality:

```
return PyNumber_ToBase(your_number, 16);
```

[`PyNumber_ToBase`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/number.html) also exists in 2.6 and 2.7, though `hex` doesn't use it in the 2.x line.

Comment: Thanks! I should have looked in the abstract number protocol API, not the concrete integer API... :)

Comment: @circular-ruin: Thanks! That didn't show up when I searched for it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, one way to do it is something like:

```
  PyObject *fmt_string = PyUnicode_FromString("{0:x}");
  if (!fmt_string)
    return NULL;

  PyObject *hex_rep_string = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(fmt_string, "format", int_obj);
  Py_DECREF(fmt_string);
  if (!hex_rep_string)
    {
      return NULL;
    }
```

but it seems there must be a better/more canonical way...